# How to choose a desired code for a Subroutine among various options during the start of a run

Tags: fortran

Let's say I want to perform an operation in my main program (in Fortran). And lets say that operation is finding minimum number in a 1D array. I wish to do so by passing the array into the call subroutine and the subroutine will print the minimum value on the screen. There are different ways or algorithms to find minimum value in an array. Lets say I have 100 different methods: Method1, Method2..... Method100. Now I want to try using each one of these methods separately (I don't want to try all of them at once, but one method in each run). I don't want to create 100 different subroutines and change the code every time to decide which one to call, rather I want to mention in the input file which one I want to choose. So basically, the computer has to read the input file (to know which method to use) and perform the task using the specified method amongst different methods available.

I can write a Subroutine dump all the methods into that subroutine and put an IF condition to choose among various methods. But IF conditions are in efficient particularly on GPUs, I want to know the most efficient way of doing this.

```
MAIN PROGRAM

      INTEGER Method !will be read from input file

      Array = [12,5,3,4,1,7,4,3]

      call print_Minimum(Array)

END PROGRAM


SUBROUTINE print_Minimum(Array)

      IF (METHOD == 1)

          <method 1 code>

      ELSE IF (METHOD == 2)

          <method 2 code>
        :
        :
        :
        :
      ELSE IF (METHOD == 100)

          <method100 code>

      END IF

END SUBROUTINE
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand why you want the If statement in the subroutine. Why not have 100 different subroutines and have the if (or probably better Select Case) statement outside that?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably best done using a function pointer and/or functions as arguments.

You can set a function pointer to a certain function and do this in your nested ifs and you can pass functions as arguments.

Both methods are implemented in the following example.

```
module minimum_mod
    implicit none
    private
    public :: get_min_t, naive_min, time_min_function

    abstract interface
        integer pure function get_min_t(X)
            integer, intent(in) :: X(:)
        end function
    end interface

contains

    subroutine time_min_function(f, X)
        procedure(get_min_t) :: f
        integer, intent(in) :: X(:)
        integer :: res
        res = f(X)
        write(*, *) res
    end subroutine

    integer pure function naive_min(X)
        integer, intent(in) :: X(:)
        integer :: i
        naive_min = huge(naive_min)
        do i = 1, size(X)
            naive_min = min(naive_min, X(i))
        end do
    end function

end module

program time_min_finders
    use minimum_mod, only: get_min_t, naive_min, time_min_function
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: test_set(5) = [1, 10, 3, 5, 7]
    procedure(get_min_t), pointer :: f

    f => naive_min

    call time_min_function(f, test_set)

end program
```

PS: Note that you can now do all the timinig logic inside `time_min_function`.

Comment: what is the advantage compared to using a large `select case...end select` block and calling the functions explicitly?

Comment: Yes - I thought about doing it with extensible types and type bound procedures (as I prefer to avoid function pointers) but given the OP wants to read the method in from a file ultimately I can see no way to avoid a big If or Select Case.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of a derived type that contains a function pointer, effectively an array of function pointers. Then in principle you could initialize the function pointers to point at all of your test functions so that you could refer to each function by its index without having to test with a SELECT CASE of IF block: this is the typical Fortran way. However, either I've got the syntax for initialization wrong or my old version of gfortran just isn't capable, so I had to initialize one at a time. Sigh.

```
module minfuncs
   implicit none
   abstract interface
      function func(array)
         integer, intent(in) :: array(:)
         integer func
      end function func
   end interface
   type func_node
      procedure(func), NOPASS, pointer :: f
   end type func_node
!   type(func_node) :: method(5) = [func_node(min_1),func_node(min_2), &
!      func_node(min_3),func_node(min_4),func_node(min_5)]
   contains
      function min_1(array)
         integer, intent(in) :: array(:)
         integer min_1
         integer i
         min_1 = array(1)
         do i = 2, size(array)
            min_1 = min(min_1,array(i))
         end do
      end function min_1
      function min_2(array)
         integer, intent(in) :: array(:)
         integer min_2
         integer i
         min_2 = array(1)
         do i = 8, size(array), 7
            min_2 = min(min_2,array(i-6),array(i-5),array(i-4), &
               array(i-3),array(i-2),array(i-1),array(i))
         end do
         do i = i-6, size(array)
            min_2 = min(min_2, array(i))
         end do
      end function min_2
      function min_3(array)
         integer, intent(in) :: array(:)
         integer min_3
         integer i
         min_3 = array(1)
         do i = 2, size(array)
            min_3 = min_3-dim(min_3,array(i))
         end do
      end function min_3
      function min_4(array)
         integer, intent(in) :: array(:)
         integer min_4
         integer ymm(8)
         integer i
         if(size(array) >= 8) then
            ymm = array(1:8)
            do i = 16, size(array), 8
               ymm = min(ymm,array(i-7:i))
            end do
            min_4 = minval([ymm,array(i-7:size(array))])
         else
            min_4 = minval(array)
         end if
      end function min_4
      function min_5(array)
         integer, intent(in) :: array(:)
         integer min_5
         min_5 = minval(array)
      end function min_5
end module minfuncs

program test
   use minfuncs
   implicit none
   integer, parameter :: N = 75
   integer i
   integer :: A(N) = modulo(5*[(i,i=1,N)]**2,163)
!   type(func_node) :: method(5) = [func_node(min_1),func_node(min_2), &
!      func_node(min_3),func_node(min_4),func_node(min_5)]
   type(func_node) method(5)
   method(1)%f => min_1
   method(2)%f => min_2
   method(3)%f => min_3
   method(4)%f => min_4
   method(5)%f => min_5
   do i = 1, size(method)
      write(*,*) method(i)%f(A)
   end do
end program test
```

Output:

```
   2
   2
   2
   2
   2
```